# Bad File Name when using Excel to find words in a Word Document

Tags: excel, syntax-error, ms-word, vba

I'm using the code below to loop through some data on an Excel spreadsheet and open a Word document.  I want to then cycle through a word document and find all of the words that were on the Excel sheet.  This works okay until I try and find the words on the Excel sheet and then I get a "bad file name" message.  I've highlighted the line below where the error occurs.  I'm sure it is a syntax error, I just don't know what the correct syntax is.  Thanks for the help.......

```
    Dim MyDB() As String
    Dim MyCol() As String
    Dim MyDBCnt As Integer
    Dim MyColCnt As Integer
    Dim DBCnt As Integer
    Dim ResRow As Integer
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim PrevRow As Integer
    ResRow = 1
    r = 5
    x = 1
    PrevRow = 4

    Do Until Len(Trim(Cells(r, 4))) + Len(Trim(Cells(r, 5))) = 0
        DoEvents
        ReDim Preserve MyDB(1 To x)

       If (Trim(Cells(r, 4)) & "." & Trim(Cells(r, 5))) = (Trim(Cells(PrevRow, 4)) & "." & Trim(Cells(PrevRow, 5))) Then
'           do nothing
        Else
            MyDB(x) = Trim(Cells(r, 4)) & "." & Trim(Cells(r, 5))
            x = x + 1
        End If

        r = r + 1
        PrevRow = PrevRow + 1
    Loop

    x = x - 1
    MyDBCnt = x
    r = 5
    x = 1

    Do Until Len(Trim(Cells(r, 4))) + Len(Trim(Cells(r, 5))) = 0
        DoEvents
        ReDim Preserve MyCol(1 To x)
        MyCol(x) = Trim(Cells(r, 6))
        r = r + 1
        x = x + 1

    Loop

    x = x - 1
    MyColCnt = x

    Worksheets("Results").Activate
    MyLastRow = Cells.Find("*", [a1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    ResRow = MyLastRow

    Set WordApp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("R:\Report Web\SQL Doc.docx")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordDoc.Activate

    tmp = WordDoc.Name
    Dim j As Integer

    DBCnt = 1

    With WordApp.Selection
        Do Until DBCnt > MyDBCnt
            DoEvents
            With Documents(WordDoc).Find    ***ERROR OCCURS HERE
                .Text = MyDB(DBCnt)
                j = 0

                Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
                    DoEvents
                    j = j + 1
                Loop
            End With

            If j > 0 Then
                MsgBox MyDB(DBCnt) & " was found " & j & " times."
            End If
            DBCnt = DBCnt + 1
        Loop
  End With
```

Comment: Have you tried `With Documents(WordDoc).Find(MyDB(DBCnt))`?

Comment: @findwindow.......Same result (Bad File Name) on the same line.  thanks.....

Comment: Oh yea duh XD See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Find is not a valid property of the Document object. You need to use it on either the Selection or the Range object. For example:

```
Dim rngFind as Word.Range
Set rngFind = WordDoc.Content
With rngFind.Find

End With
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error here:  Set doc = Documents(WordDoc).  WordDoc = "SQL Doc.docx".  Thanks for your help

Comment: Ah, OK, I was just looking at the single line of your code and hadn't noticed that WordDoc was already a document object. In that case: Set rngFind = WordDoc.Content and forget the "doc" object in my code snippet (I'll edit my Answer)